# Plot window appears but no plot - R debian stretch

Tags: r, linux, plot, debian

I am running the following R script from the R terminal,

```
library(xts)
library(csv)
library(graphics)

dt <- data.frame(read.csv("/home/russellb/tmp.csv", header=TRUE, sep=','));
df <- xts(dt[-c[1], as.Date(dt$Datum));

print(head(df[,2]));
plot(df[,2])
```

What I get in my R console is the following,

```
           Amount$ 
2016-03-03  630200
2016-03-04 2971100
2016-03-05 3023800
2016-03-06 1669300
2016-03-07 1704900
2016-03-08 1415500
```

No error or warning messages.

The plot window appears but no data has been plotted and the plot window is empty with the title "**R Graphics: Device 2 (ACTIVE)**".

When I type,

```
x11()
```

in the R console, a plot window appears and when I type the following,

```
plot(1:100)
```

I get the data plotted in the window.

I tried adding `x11()` in the script but without any luck. I am running **R-3.3.3** on my **Debian-stretch 9.1**

My `sessionInfo()` output is as follows,

```
R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] lattice_0.20-34 csv_0.5         xts_0.10-0      zoo_1.8-0      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] grid_3.3.3
```

**Output of dput(head(dat))**

```
structure(list(Datum = structure(c(505L, 504L, 503L, 
502L, 501L, 500L), .Label = c("2016-03-03", "2016-03-04", "2016-03-05", 
"2016-03-06", "2016-03-07", "2016-03-08", "2016-03-09", "2016-03-10", 
"2016-03-11", "2016-03-12", "2016-03-13", "2016-03-14", "2016-03-15", 
"2016-03-16", "2016-03-17", "2016-03-18", "2016-03-19", "2016-03-20", 
...
"2017-07-17", "2017-07-18", "2017-07-19", "2017-07-20", "2017-07-21", 
"2017-07-22", "2017-07-23"), class = "factor"), Amount = c(1700500L, 
2286600L, 3018700L, 2012100L, 2357600L, 1983500L), DM50 = c(230L, 
294L, 454L, 267L, 316L, 270L), DM10 = c(226L, 399L, 364L, 330L, 
371L, 298L), DM5 = c(516L, 699L, 636L, 573L, 676L, 549L), DM1 = c(665L, 681L, 667L, 606L, 686L, 610L)), .Names = c("Datum", Amount", "X50", "X10", "X5", "X1"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should post output of `dput(head(dt))`. It's not clear what your dataframe has in it. It's very weird to see a "$" in a column name.

Comment: My `print(head(df[,2]))` output says the data has been loaded properly. But not plotted. Thank you @42-

Comment: added the info @42-

Comment: I think you abbreviated the output. It's not possible to assign that structure to a variable name. What I can see looks lind of odd. The `.Names = c("Datum", Amount", "X50", "X10", "X5", "X1")` attribute has different character values than the "interior" of the structure: Datum,Amount, DM5000, DM1000, DM500, DM100

Comment: Yes. I did before posting and forgot to change the corresponding entries inline. Now they're consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the problem arises because the first column which appears to be a Date is not really an R-Date. It's a factor. You could convert it to a "real" Date by executing:

```
df$Datum <- as.Date( as.character( df$Datum ) )
```

R's plotting functions handle factors quite differently than they do Dates.